# Animating screen scroll with html

Tags: html, animation

OK I was wondering if someone could explain how this works
(https://doodles.google.com/d4g/?utm_source=launchhpp&utm_campaign=jan25)
because I've been wanting to do something just like this for a long time I just cant figure out how it works.
If you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the page, it is composed of svg elements.
So basically what they are doing is catching the scroll event and editing the state of the svg. You can learn more about svg elements [here](http://svgtutorial.com/manipulating-svg-with-javascript/) .
Another way to do this is to use sprites and animate them in javascript or through a library.

If you're going to do it, expect a long session of trial and error on your first time.